# Nav drawer items are pink instead of black only in Android 8

Tags: android, android-layout

**EDIT:** I just realised it isn't actually the accent color. I tried changing the accent color and while it changed everywhere else, the color of my nav items stayed pink. I just assumed it was the accent color because it was similar to it. Now I have no idea where that color is coming from.

I've just noticed that in my app the nav drawer items are the accent color instead of being black when running on Android 8.

In Android 7 they are still black it is only Android 8 that it is different for. Also when looking at the design preview in Android Studio it shows them as black for API 26 (Android 8) but when it runs it is the accent color.

Here are a few images demonstrating the issue:

This is what it looks like in the design preview in Android Studio and on versions before 8:
[image]

And on Android 8:

[image]

Note that the primary color still works when an item is active (which is how I want it) but if I try and change the tint of the icon or text to black it no longer is able to change to the primary color when active so that doesn't work as a work around.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#F44336</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#D32F2F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

</resources>
```

xml for nav activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_nav_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: can you add you style.xml and color.xml file here

Comment: Sorry should have included those to begin with. Included now.

Comment: It looks correct. Can you clean your build, uninstall the app and run it.

Comment: Still pink in Android 8 unfortunately. I will also add my xml for the nav activity incase the problem is there.

Comment: After changing the accent color the pink items stayed pink so it clearly isn't coming from the accent color. I have no idea where this color could be coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I managed to work it out. Turns out I was using dependencies for themes with api level 23 and they were breaking in Android 8. Managed to fix the issue by upgrading my dependencies, target SDK and compile SDK version to 26.

Comment: Thousand thanks to sharing this information , I solved my issue using this solution I was using Sublimenavigationview which was showing pink color items only in Android Oreo. but after updating compile SDK to 26 and dependencies it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**Got Solution** - 
**Navigation Drawer menu item Text color Pink issue** in android 8..
I am also facing the same issue occurs in Oreo(MiA1).

*Change compile SDK version to 25.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

Update those libraries mention below(app.gradle)

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here with a newer sdk verson:

- Make sure that the **dependencies use the same version as your compile sdk version**

This solved the problem for me